# Use custom color in C++Builder 6

Tags: c++, fonts, colors, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm making an application in C++ Builder 6. I need to use my own color in the `Caption` of a `TLabel`. I mean not a standard color like `clBlue`, `clRed`, etc, but like "8c8a8a"(it's grey), "dedcdc"(it's white). There are some hue of colors that I need.

I have searched the Internet but I have not found anything.
 Is there a way to do this?

Please don't say something like "Yes, change to VS/QT or something modern".
 I don't want to change away from C++Builder 6.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hex-encoded number, eg `0x8c8a8a`.  This can be done in the Object Inspector at design-time, or in code at run-time:

```
Label1->Font->Color = (TColor) 0x8c8a8a;
```

Alternatively, use the Win32 [`RGB()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162937.aspx) macro and type-cast the returned [`COLORREF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx) to `TColor`. This can only be done in code at run-time:

```
Label1->Font->Color = (TColor) RGB (0x8c, 0x8a, 0x8a);
```

Comment: Thank u, it works, but I have one problem. Not every color is the same as RGB. White hue is fine, but when i want to use blue: 99ccff, it gives me something like gold/yellow.

Comment: @Persantarus colors in VCL are always in RGB. In hex, the bytes are arranged in 0x00BBGGRR, so use 0x00ffcc99 instead. That is blue hue. That is why you should use `RGB()`, then there is no ambiguity.